# reloadData() break collection view cell swift

Tags: ios, swift, collections, view, uicollectionviewcell

Without calling `reloadData()` it displays everything correctly, like this:

[image]

But after calling reloadData ()

[image]

My code - https://github.com/Invictorp/CollectionViewProblem

The problem occurs just after calling reloadData ()

Comment: You have uploaded same image for both correct and wrong and github url also not available.

Comment: yeah I can't see any deference, also the GitHub link working :/